cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils' error in loader.load() call
I am importing UnstructuredPDFLoader from langchain.document_loaders and trying to load a pdf file using the following command.
from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader("./xx.pdf")
data = loader.load()

Getting the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils (C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pdfminer\utils.py). 

Tried some resolutions given on a similar topic, but no luck.
loader.load() should have loaded the file without any errors. Tried instal/uninstall pdfminer and pdfminer.six combinations, but it didn't resolve the issue

Please, add full traceback for this error

I m using langchain-community==0.2.12 version
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader, TextLoader, Docx2txtLoader

# load PDF documents
loader = DirectoryLoader(saved_file_dir, glob='./*.pdf', loader_cls=PyPDFLoader) 
loader.load()

# load text files
loader = DirectoryLoader(saved_file_dir, glob="**/*.txt", use_multithreading=True, loader_cls=TextLoader)

# load docx files
loader = Docx2txtLoader(file_path)

